# What is the stalling speed of a Cessna 172SP at an altitude of 2000 feet?

Tags: aircraft-performance, cessna-172, v-speeds

What is the stalling speed of the Cessna 172SP if the temperature is +11 degrees Celsius, the power is off, the CG is at the forward limit, the flaps are at 0 degrees and the altitude is 2000 feet?

Comment: this looks like a quiz question. could you tell us why you are unable to answer? where are you encountering problems?

Comment: What is the AOA? It is important to realize that a plane can stall at any speed, what matters is when you have separation of the flow from the wing, which occurs at a certain angle of attack, not necessarily speed.

Comment: @RonBeyer stall speed is a well defined quantity

Comment: @Federico For level flight, yes, but increase the load factor (turn while staying level) and it changes. This is a major cause of accidents called an [accelerated stall/spin](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2016/september/flight-training-magazine/technique).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to determine the speed from the Pilot's Operating Handbook, which is available online. See page 5, and Section 5.

http://www.airilm.com/wp-content/uploads/172S-POH.pdf

Comment: Downvoted for providing facts? Really?

Comment: Looks to me like this is ***exactly*** the answer this question deserves. +1

Comment: @CrossRoads No, for providing only links.

Comment: PDF Document was not copyable - try it yourself and see.

Comment: If it's not copyable, you can type it out yourself... in this case, screenshot the chart and show how to determine the speed?

Comment: @CrossRoads we (SE network) prefer when answers contain the relevant information, and do not require people clicking on links. if you cannot copzy-paste from the pdf, then you have to re-type it by hand. (or screenshot if a chart)

Comment: Fine - 48 knots KIAS, 53 knots KCAS

Comment: if your are doing flight training or are intending to do an actual flight, i do not recommend you to calculate this type of speeds using data found online. Always refer to the Pilots Operating Handbook of the Aircraft itself.

Comment: Yes, like the one I referenced.  Or the one in the plane you are flying.